# Why is transformer coupling used in a simple slope detector? Can't the FM signal be applied directly in parallel to a tuned circuit?

Tags: rf, transformer, frequency-modulation, detection, demodulation

This is what I mean by simple slope detector:

[image]

Why can't it be like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Why is transformer coupling used in a simple slope detector?*

You don't need a transformer for a simple slope detector. This circuit would work providing you select the centre frequency to be one side of the LC tank resonant frequency: -

[image]

Or maybe this diagram from an [Analog devices article](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics_lab_fm_detectors): -

[image]

Comment: just from curiosity: what is the use of the transformer? some kind of sensitivity enhancement? antenna matching?

Comment: @Andy aka Do transformer provides some additional advantage ?

Comment: I reckon that a moderately coupled (but not excessively coupled) transformer might be able to produce a double parallel tuning effect that gives more slope hence a higher gain for the demodulation to an AM signal. I'm not 100% on this so maybe if you have some time try and simulate it.

Comment: @Andyaka Not only that, but double tuning can keep the slope more linear across the required range, reducing distortion on the demodulated signal. They can be a right b*tch to tune for minimum distortion.

Comment: @BrianDrummond ta for that dude. I had a suspicion it was that but couldn't find anything explicit on t'web